# How to find folder in google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have implement the function upload file to google drive. I have done it following the guide in [quick start](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart).

Now i'm doing the function upload file to specific folder *(Ex: upload file to "My_Folder_name")*. I found the sample in [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert). The trouble is how can i get the **parentId** *(folder id)* if i only know the name of folder.

I could not find any function to search folder by name...

Is the only one way to get folder by get all the files, then check *MimeType* is equals with *"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"* and  compare it with folder name.

```
if("application/vnd.google-apps.folder".equals(body.getMimeType()) && "My_Folder_name".equals(body.getTitle()) ){
            ....        
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

Edit as per Mike's comment:

> name='foldername' is no longer correct in 2022

The new syntax should be:
`mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and title = 'foldername'`

---

Original answer:

Query should be as follows:

`mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='foldername'`

In Python:

```
service.files().list(q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='foldername'",
                                         spaces='drive',
                                         fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                         pageToken=page_token).execute()
```

Note: `name='foldername'` not `title='foldername'`

Comment: In my case, even after having the correct code the folder wasn't being listed. Figured out since I was using a service account to upload files (to the folder on Google Drive), I needed to share that folder with the service account too.

Comment: Can we crawl one or more folders inside the parent folder? 
In other words, Can we download the files from multiple parent folders? 
For example, 
2022 Folder > January > 01142022.csv
2022 Folder > February > 02142022.csv

I have 2022 (year) as a grandparent and January(month) as a parent folder and 02142022.csv as child file.

how to download the files every month which arrives every month. I can only give the folder id of 2022 hard-coded and month-based folder id has to be taken up automatically. 

Please guide. I want to download all CSV files with their parent and grand parents

Comment: Sorry @Gaurav, comment section is not for asking further questions about a very specific problem you are facing. Of course what you're saying is possible, you just need to know how to code it. Do some reading and write your script step by step, take baby steps and solve each little problem separately. We're not here to do your work for you

Comment: name='foldername' is no longer correct in 2022

Comment: @MikeJohnsonJr care to share the correct syntax?

Comment: title = 'foldername'

Answer (score 13):

You can add the `q` query parameter to your request URL and use the Drive query language to restrict your search:

https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters

To search for folders only and restrict the search by title, your query should look like:

```
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and title = 'My_Folder_name'
```

Comment: how do you do this programatically?

Comment: in Java, use the setQ method

Comment: would it be possible to get a code example or documentation with code examples?

Comment: add `and trashed = false` if you only want untrashed folders

Comment: If I have same name folder in google drive then it will give two folder ?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you're looking for a Typescript/Javascript answer here's it.

```
const fileList = await this.getInstance().files.list({
        q: `(mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='${folderName}') and trashed = false`,
        fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
        supportsAllDrives: true,
        spaces: 'drive',
        orderBy: 'name desc'
      });
```

if you want to search within another folder then you can do

```
const fileList = await this.getInstance().files.list({
        q: `"${parentFolderId}" in parents and (mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='${folderName}') and trashed = false`,
        fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
        supportsAllDrives: true,
        spaces: 'drive',
        orderBy: 'name desc'
      });
```

Of course, you need to modify a little bit for your usecase. Especially how you get your Drive Instance

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

Use files.list (which gives full file resources)(https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list).
Amend your query to add the parent id you want to search in.

mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'folderId' in parents

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
/*String pageToken = null;
            do {
                FileList fileList = driveService.files().list().setQ("'" + parentFolderId + "' in parents")
                        .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id,parents,name,mimeType)")
                        .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();

                if (fileList.getFiles().size() == 0)
                    System.out.println("No data inside the folder");

                    for (File file : fileList.getFiles()) {
                        System.out.println(file.getId());
                    }
                pageToken = fileList.getNextPageToken();
            } while (pageToken != null);*/
```